# Modulo Ring Homomorphisms

Tags: modular-arithmetic, group-homomorphism

How to I find all the possible values of $f(1)$ when $f$ is the ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z}$?

My first thought was to see when they are equal like $1$mod6=$1$mod$42$ etc but then this doesn't give me the correct answer and I am not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing for finding a homomorphism of the underlying additive groups is that
$$f(1)+f(1)+f(1)+f(1)+f(1)+f(1)=f(0)=0\, $$
So, $7\,|\,f(1)$ must hold.

To preserve multiplication as well, $f(1)$ must also be an idempotent: $f(1)^2=f(1)$, which further decreases the number possibilities.

If we want a *unital* ring homomorphism (which is, by the way, the most standard meaning of 'ring homomorphism'), then it means $f(1)=1$ which is impossible in this case because of the first item above.

Comment: For a rng-homomorphism, $f(1)$ must be idempotent.

Comment: Yes, indeed. First I answered for the case of Abelian groups.

Comment: What does $7 \mid f(1)$ mean in $\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z}$?