# Finding ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

List all the possible values of (1) when  is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/70\mathbb{Z}$.

My attempt: based on this post, [Modulo Ring Homomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3893992/modulo-ring-homomorphisms)
I have written python: (solve $f(1)$ as $x$)

```
x=0
while x <=69:
    if x % 101 == 0:
        if x == x**2:
            print(x)
    x=x+1
```

The ouput is x=0, which is an incorrect answer.

Thank you for your help.

---update:---
solved.

```
x=0
while x <=69:
    if 100*x % 70 == 0:
        if x % 70 == x**2 % 70:
            print(x)
    x = x+1
```

Thank you for your up-votes.

Comment: Please edit your post to explain the detail of what you had in mind for each step of your algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$0=g(100)=100g(1)$$ in $\Bbb Z/70\Bbb Z$, what can you say about $g(1)$?

Comment: Isn't this rather a comment?

Comment: $100g(1)$ is divisible by 70?